# Why do I get 'Cannot read property 'props' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my create-react-app/redux I have a 'connected component':

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  debugger;
  const { datas } = this.props;

  debugger;
  return <div className="App">{datas}}</div>;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    datas: state
  };
};

// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
//   return {
//     onRequestDog: () => dispatch({ type: "API_CALL_REQUEST_POST" })
//   };
// };

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(App);
```

The redux is configured in the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { watcherSaga } from "./sagas";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from './redux.js'

//hookup saga
// create the saga middleware
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

// dev tools middleware
const reduxDevTools =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__();

// create a redux store with our reducer above and middleware
let store = createStore(reducer, reduxDevTools );

// run the saga
//sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga);


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

When I run this app I see this in the console:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

How can I debug this issue/ what is the cause of it?

Comment: Troubleshooting: What line throws that error? Error messages are typically very helpful with that sort of information, and including that (and reviewing the line) can be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is for class based components:

```
function App(props) {
  debugger;
  const { datas } = props;

  debugger;
  return <div className="App">{datas}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Also `props` needs to be a function argument, as shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!